# Angular 2 select option State

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am using select2(https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2.) in my Angular 2 application. The form is based on reactive/Model based form. 
I want to know how to activate its different states(dirty,touched,pristine) for the select option. The problem i am facing is in my edit form when I change the select option values, it does not make the form dirty or touched. Please help!!
[image]

```html
<form id="validation-form" class="form-horizontal form-label-left parsleyjs" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false" novalidate 
    (ngSubmit)="saveProduct()" [formGroup]="productForm">
 <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="shelflife" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Shelf Life (Month) <span class="required">*</span>
               <div *ngIf="productForm.get('shelflife').errors">
                  <ul class="parsley-errors-list filled" id="parsley-id-5"><li class="parsley-required">This value is required</li></ul>
                </div>
              </label>
              <div class="col-md-7">
                <select2 class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" [data]="shelflife_data | async" [value]="selectedShelflife | async" [width]="'100%'" 
                    (valueChanged)="onShelflifeChanged($event)" [options]="{theme: 'bootstrap'}"></select2>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Below is the Component ts code

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {

   jQuery('.parsleyjs').parsley({
      errorsContainer: function (elem, isRadioOrCheckbox) {
        return jQuery(elem.$element).closest('.form-group').children('label');
      }
    });

    this.productForm = this.fb.group({
      gtin: [''],
      fdoname_en: [''],
      fdoname_fa: [''],
      newirc: [''],
      singleunitpackage: [''],
      multiunitpackage: [''],
      shelflife: ['', [Validators.required]],
      dosageform: ['', [Validators.required]],
      routeadmin: [''],
      productcategory: [''],
      status: [''],
      genericname_en:['', [Validators.required]]
    });

    this.loadShelflife();
    this.loadGenericProduct() 
    this.loadDosageForm();
    this.loadProductCat();

    // Read the gtin from the route parameter
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.gtin = params['gtin'];
        this.getProduct(this.gtin);
      }
    );

    const genericnameControl = this.productForm.controls["genericname_en"];
    genericnameControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      //this.productForm.controls['genericname_en'].markAsDirty();
      if (value === '-1') {
        genericnameControl.setErrors({
          required: true
        });
      }
    });

    const dosageformControl = this.productForm.controls["dosageform"];
    dosageformControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      //this.productForm.controls['dosageform'].markAsDirty();
      if (value === '-1') {
        dosageformControl.setErrors({
          required: true
        });
      }
    });

    const shelflifeControl = this.productForm.controls["shelflife"];
    shelflifeControl.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      //this.productForm.controls['shelflife'].markAsDirty();
      if (value === '-1') {
        shelflifeControl.setErrors({
          required: true
        });
      }
    });
  }

saveProduct(): void {
if (this.productForm.dirty && this.productForm.valid) {
  console.log("INSIDE SAVE PRODUCT!!!!!! " + this.productForm.value.productcategory);
  let gtin = this.route.snapshot.params['gtin'];
  let p = Object.assign({}, this.product, this.productForm.value);
  this.productDataService.saveProduct(p,gtin)
            .subscribe(
                () => this.onProductComplete(),
                (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
} else if (!this.productForm.dirty) {
  this.onProductComplete();
}
  }
```

Comment: Show us some code please! HTML and the Component

Comment: We can't determine whether you are using Template Driven or Model Driven forms.

Comment: I am using Model Driven forms and I have added the HTML code

Comment: That's not enough. Where is your `<form>` element? How did you instantiate the form?

Comment: Check this out, I don't see any issues: http://plnkr.co/edit/2YzZrmJ5v3oKrg6PIsAU?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This sample is using Textfield and I have no issue with that. I have issue with that select2 I am using.

Comment: Read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the `select` component you are using, I can see from the source code that the author has not properly implement the `ControlValueAccessor` in his library so angular is not able to pick up the state changes made by the select boxes you are using.

If you need to check the forms state, I would ditch that nasty library and move to something else.

Source: https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/blob/master/lib/ng2-select2.component.ts

Comment: If you check the source code of Angular Material2 below, you'll see that they are using `registerOnChange` and `registerOnTouched` to let angular know of the state changes. This is simply not present in the library you used: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/select/select.ts

Comment: Look at this issue: https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/issues/13 The library does not support the Form at all. And there has not been any updates from him, since **August 2016**! You should really use something else.

Comment: Can you reckon some other library for select option

Comment: I personally use `material2`. It's easily customizable and you don't have to use the whole library. You can import the `MdSelectModule` only.